# How to subtract two hex color in C#?

Tags: c#, colors, hex

I want to subtract two hexadecimals in C#. How can I do that?

Something like this : 
      #7ffffff - #000123

Comment: What is your desired result? Treat them both as 24-bit integers and subtract them? What about the result being negative? Or treat them as three individual numbers that are individually subtracted? What about those results being negative?

Comment: I have a matrix and I want to color it. so if matrix element is less than specific number subtract color from #7fffff and if it is more than it add color with #7fffff.@DangerZone

Comment: I didn't ask what you want to do, I asked what you've tried so far to solve your problem of subtracting hex numbers. The reason you have 2 downvotes on this question is most likely because you haven't shown any effort on your part in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal literals are prefixed with `0x` as in `0x7fffff`. So you could assign each value to an integer and subtract them as such:

```
int color1 = 0x7fffff;
int color2 = 0x000123;

int difference = color1 - color2;
```

This is admittedly a naïve approach which will not work in a lot of cases, although given your comment, I'm thinking it will be sufficient. Consider what would happen if you subtracted a color with a larger attribute from a smaller, as in:

```
0xFF20FF - 0x003000 = 0xFEE0FF
```

I’m thinking that you would not want to borrow 1 from red, adding `0xFF` to green. In a situation like that, I might want the result to be `0xFF00FF`. In that case, you would want a method that subtracts the individual color elements with a floor of zero, as in:

```
int SubtractColors( int color1, int color2 )
{
    int red = Math.Max( 0,( color1 >> 16 ) - ( color2 >> 16 ) );
    int green = Math.Max( 0, ( ( color1 >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) - ( ( color2 >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) );
    int blue = Math.Max( 0, ( color1 & 0xFF ) - ( color2 & 0xFF ) );

    return ( red << 16 ) + ( green << 8 ) + blue;
}
```

We’re doing some “bit bashing” here which a lot of less experienced programmers are not familiar with. If the code above doesn’t entirely make sense, you may want to learn about:

[`>>` right shift operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx)

[`<<` left shift operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)

[`&` bitwise AND operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)